# Server with dynamic IP

Tags: android

I am making an app that uses socket programming. Client side is programmed using android and server side using Java. The IP address of the server may change and the IP address has to be kept secure and private. 
I do not want the users to install the app again and again when the IP of server changes.

Comment: This isn't a question. I assume you're wondering how to handle the changes in the server's IP address?

Also, it's not really going to be possible to hide the server's address from your client applications unless you have all traffic forwarded through an intermediate server or VPN.

Comment: Have settings to change IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use domain for your server . your domain is static and not change dynamically.

for example your domain is  : **yoursystem.com**

now your server ip is : **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**

and tomarow your ip change to **yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy**

but your domain address is static and user can conect to your domain.
if your privacy is important you can improve your privacy by set token for your user and ...

Comment: what is your server os ? linux or windows ?

Comment: in windows your computer name is your domain . you can test by ping your computer name with other computers in local network. Usually computer name is yourname-pc